# Any exit status without explicitly using return /exit

Tags: c++, c, gcc, exit

This actually bugging me from quite sometime now.The question is like this : **How to set the the exit status of a program to any value without explicitly using return/exit in gcc/g++ ?**
Let us consider this piece of code : (Takes input from stdin and print
it to the stdout until a zero input 0 is encountered)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  while(scanf("%d",&n) && n>0 )
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

In my system (which is **windows + mingw**) it is returning 1,How to make
it to return 0 or anything else implicitly without explicitly using
exit/return ?

**EDIT :**

I modified the code a bit :

```
int f(int n) { 
  return (n>0);
}

int main(){
  int n;
  while(scanf("%d",&n)&&f(n))
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
```

It's now returning 0 implicitly,but I couldn't draw any firm conclusion from this.

Comment: You forget to mention the compiler and the runtime environment. Compiler: gcc, runtime environment: http://spoj.pl

Comment: What is the return code after you delete "&& n>0" from the code?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  I think that would be a helpful edit.

Comment: This is quite equivalent to asking "how to make it return 42?"  With the return statement, of course.  Or you could write some assembly to assign the EAX register.

Comment: @sambowry: No exit status the program will not terminate ever ;)

Comment: Sorry, my fault: delete "&& n" (keep ">0")

Comment: @ sambowry:Do you mean : `while(scanf("%d",&n)>0)` ?! :O

Comment: I mean: `echo 'main(n){while(scanf("%i",&n)>0)printf("n:%i\n",n);}'|gcc -x c -;./a.out</dev/null;echo exit_code: $?` (run on linux; i dont know how to do it on windows)

Comment: Why don't you want to call return or exit?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ and in C99, leaving main without executing exit() or return should be equivalent to return 0 (see 5.1.2.2.3 for C, 3.6.1/5 for C++), C89 leaved that undefined if I recall correctly.

Comment: Yes,I am aware of this but still some GCC versions is behaving strange for some programs like the the one I showed above,

Comment: Undefined is undefined... as the support for C99 by gcc is still incomplete, you probably tested version before and after that feature has been added.
I would not be suprised that the result of main was the result of the last function called, if you don't do too many things after.  That seems to explain the behaviour you observe in your edit.

Answer (score 2):

I think your implementation is using the return value of the last function called inside main() -- not a behaviour you can depend on, of course. (And may change with compilation options, i.e. inlining)

(This is probably due to the value left in the EAX register, as has been mentioned in the comments.)

The best I can come up with:

```
static int program_exit_value;

void setExitValue(int value)
{
    program_exit_value = value;
}

int main(void)
{
    ...

    return program_exit_value;
}
```

Which uses a `return` statement but has the advantage that it is ANSI-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The point is your program will eventually terminate - for example, the runtime will call `ExitProcess()` on Windows or an equivalent function on another OS. The primitive used to end the program will set the error code (exit status) that will override the code previously set by you directly.

Maybe there're some C++ runtime implementations that allow what you want, but overall the behavior is as I described above.